# Dependabot confluent dependencies

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, dependabot

My project has a dependency on `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients` library.

The latest version is `7.3.1-ccs`, but dependabot keeps creating prs to update it to `7.3.1-ce`, which license is not friendly.

Any way to configure dependabot to ignore versions ending in `ce`?

Comment: Why do you need Confluent versions, vs Apache `kafka-clients:3.3.x` anyway?

Comment: Apache was giving weird warns

Comment: Such as? I have never seen it give a warning